# Heroku auto restore

Tags: database, heroku, automation, database-backups, pg-restore

I need to implement an automatic trasfer of daily backups from one DB to another DB. Both DB's and apps are hosted on heroku. 
I know this is possible if to do it manually from local machine with the command:

```
heroku pgbackups:restore DATABASE `heroku pgbackups:url --app production-app` --app staging-app
```

But this process should be automated and run not from local machine. 
I have an idea to write a rake which will execute this command; and run this rake daily with the help of Heroku Scheduler add-on.

Any ideas how it is better to do this? Or maybe there is a better way for this task?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe you can add a daily chronjob that will do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue myself. It appeared to be not so complex. Here is the solution, maybe it'll be useful to somebody else:
1. I wrote a script which copies the latest dump from a certain server to the DB of the current server

```
namespace :backup do
  desc "copy the latest dump from a certain server to the DB of the current server"
  task restore_last_write_dump: :environment do
    last_dump_url = %x(heroku pgbackups:url --app [source_app_name])
    system("heroku pgbackups:restore [DB_to_target_app] '#{last_dump_url}' -a [target_app_name] --confirm [target_app_name]")
    puts "Restored dump: #{last_dump_url}"
  end

end
```

2. To avoid authenication upon each request to the servers, craete a file .netrc in the app root (see details here https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/authentication#usage-examples)
3. Setup Scheduler add-on for heroku and add our rake task along with the frequency of its running.

That is all.